# Flutter SfCharts label padding

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, syncfusion

How can I add padding to the labels, or position them further away from the plotting area? It currently looks like this, but I want to increase the red space:

[image]

I am using the `SfCartesianChart` from the [flutter_syncfusion_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the **majorTickLines** property in the axis, using this you can achieve your requirement by setting the size of the tick and setting the color as transparent. I have attached the code snippet below for your reference.

Code snippet:

```dart
primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(

    majorTickLines:

        const MajorTickLines(size: 15, color: Colors.transparent)),
```

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-customization#tick-lines-customization